# postfix: name service error

Tags: centos, postfix

```
postfix/error[2874]: 1398FA00AC7: to=<foo@mydomain.com>, relay=none, delay=0.12, delays=0.1/0/0/0.02, dsn=4.3.5, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=postmaster.mydomain.lan type=A: Host not found)
```

I am unable to figure out why postmaster.mydomain.lan stopped resolving as i can't find out if there was an A record for it to begin with.

postconf -n output:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = localhost
inet_protocols = ipv4
mail_owner = postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/README_FILES
relayhost = postmaster.mydomain.lan
```

Update: Figured this out. A dns record for postmaster.mydomain.lan was overwritten while doing an update to our zone transfer file :/

Comment: Can you `ping postmaster.mydomain.lan`? What does `dig postmaster.mydomain.lan ANY` return? Check your `/etc/resolv.conf` file.

Comment: @Thomas By default `smtp_host_lookup` is set to `dns`.  `ping` uses `gethostbyname(3)`, which is irrelevant.  Only `dig` is useful here.

Comment: dig does not return any A record. I have tried the dns server to resolve other internal domains and those work fine. I can't tell what A record was being returned for postmaster.mydomain.lan at some point earlier when this was working. I can't find anything under the dns zone files either :/